# How to redirect log4j logging from catalina.out to separate file?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

Have created log4j.properties file in my project as below, but the log file(test-service.log) is not getting created instead the log messages are getting logged in catalina.out how to resolve this.......

```
    log4j.debug=TRUE
    log4j.rootLogger=WARN, R
    log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.R.File=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/logs/test-service.log
    log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=1000KB
    log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5
    log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS}-%t-%x-%-5p-%-10c:%m%n
```

Comment: where in your project did you place this file?

Comment: Have created under (project-name)/conf/log4j.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [log4j-1.2.17.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar) to WEB-INF/lib.
2. Move log4j.properties to the root of your src directory.
3. Initialize a logger in your classes like:

   private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class);

Comment: Better to define the `LOG` as a static variable for the class.

Comment: Only neccessary if used in a static context.

Comment: @Stefan - no, also helpful if your objects are short-lived and/or used from multiple threads

Comment: Can you explain why static is recommended for short-lived objects and/or multiple threads?